# Book recommendation for Lebesgue integration and Fourier Analysis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, book-recommendation

I will soon be taking a $4$-th year joint undergraduate/graduate level course on Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Analysis, which leads into the next course on Measure and Integration. I generally like to get somewhat comfortable with the material before taking pure math courses, but unlike my previous real/complex analysis classes it hasn't been clear to me from research online what a "standard" reference on these two subjects are.

> What is a good text (or texts) which introduce Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Analysis for a strong final year undergraduate?

I know that the subsequent class I shall be taking after Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Analysis (on Measure and Integration) usually uses Folland and Royden as reference texts if that provides any context.

**Topics I'd like it to cover (*a general idea*)**

*Lebesgue measure on the line, the Lebesgue integral, the monotone and dominated convergence theorems, Lp-spaces, Fourier analysis on the circle, Dirichlet kernel, Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, Fejer's theorem and the convergence of Fourier series*, ...

**Background**

As for my background, I have taken both real and complex analysis, and in our Real Analysis class we covered metric spaces, topological spaces, completeness, the Baire Category Theorem, Urysohn's Lemma, Stone-Weierstraß Theorem, Arzela-Ascoli Theorem... I may be missing a few others. Our reference texts were Rudin (the earlier chapters) and Munkres' book on Topology. I tend to prefer books like Munkres that are slightly more conversational than something like Rudin.

If I can provide any other information please let me know!

**My findings**

From what I've gathered so far, without any further information I think I would give An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series by Howard Wilcox and David Myers ([amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A736E8W)) a look.

Comment: I'd use two books for this. For integration theory (Lebesgue integral, the monotone and dominated convergence theorems, Lp-spaces) I'd use Rudin 'Real and Complex Analysis'. And for the harmonic analysis (Fourier analysis on the circle, Dirichlet kernel, Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, Fejer's theorem and the convergence of Fourier series) I'd use Katznelson 'An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis'. I strongly recommend Katznelson, I used it myself in a course of Fourier analysis and I found almost no other book that has this nice introduction to the Dirichlet and Fejer kernels etc.

Comment: When searching for textbooks, if you try the spelling **Lebesgue** (with a **G**) you may get more matches.

Comment: @GEdgar Well that's embarrassing, somehow I've been spelling it wrong for ages.... thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One book stands out:

**Princeton Lectures in Analysis**

**[REAL ANALYSIS Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiizq3BwoPSAhVEqY8KHYn8DgsQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpress.princeton.edu%2Ftitles%2F8008.html&usg=AFQjCNGbUVYFG4c-jTvg7hiTyj5O2RqM6g)**:
*Stein,Shakarchi*.

**Note**: You can also get through the other books in the series if you want. There is a book titled **[Fourier Analysis](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiizq3BwoPSAhVEqY8KHYn8DgsQFgg4MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpress.princeton.edu%2Ftitles%2F7562.html&usg=AFQjCNHIgdNViMQGuI2msfNJtrfE-3LQqw)** in this Lecture Series.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am going to take a look at it this evening.

Comment: Hope it serves you